# Seal a Concrete Basement with Seepage Flooding for Finishing

Tags: basement, sealing, basement-refinishing, flooding, epoxy

I have a basement that floods from water seepage whenever the soil outside is saturated. This can be from heavy rain, or as in this warm winter it can go all winter long from the wet soil even without heavy rain.

How can I seal out the water? There are no cracks, it appears to be just seeping in from the corner edges. Will some kind of strong epoxy work? I believe there already are French drains installed and that wouldn't seem to fix the problem anyway since it isn't just about rain.

I'd like to finish half of the basement and can't have water sitting under it that may lead to mold growth.

I'm not sure a sump pump will work as the floor doesn't really angle down in one direction, the water comes in from all edges and must be removed with different pumps/vacuums.

Comment: Sealing from the inside is usually only temporary fix.  Sealing the outside and improving drainage/removal of water is what you need.  A sump pump might be all you need, since it will remove water under the slab before it comes up

Comment: How can I seal under the building? How can a sump pump remove water from under the slab?

Comment: The sump pump pit goes goes down about 2 feet from the floor.  Cannot seal under the slab, but can add drain pipes to the pump.  Outside sealing will be done to the walls down to the footings.  Water is quite powerful and will find a way to come in, if just inside sealing is done.

Comment: See the images at https://wellwater.oregonstate.edu/groundwater/understanding-groundwater/groundwater-and-wells for how two wells interact to lower the local groundwater table. This is how a sump pit works. There's typically a French drain below the slab perimeter that creates a ring of wells. The interference pattern of these wells creates a lowered water table below your slab.

Comment: So you drill a hole all the way through the slab and put the sump pump in that? It won't compromise the integrity of the foundation?

Comment: I wonder why the french drain isn't working as you describe it